# Laravel Exception handler logs also the request

Tags: php, laravel, exception, error-handling

I'm working on a Laravel 5.8 project, and I want to log inside the daily log file the request that has caused the exception, if some exception occurs.

I've tried this in the `public function report(Exception $exception)`

```
parent::render(request());
```

but it doesn't work at all. I've also tried this

```
\Log::error(json_encode(request()));
```

But it logs this

```
local.ERROR: {"attributes":{},"request":{},"query":{},"server":{},"files":{},"cookies":{},"headers":{}}
```

How should i do it? I need it in order to understand which request has caused that exception, and if it's possible, i need to log also other values, but i think that solved this, i can reuse the code to logs also the others

Comment: Show more code please.

Comment: there is no more code, inside the `Handler.php`, inside the public function `public function report(Exception $exception)` i have only `parent::report($exception);` and i need there to also log the request, if you need some specific other pieces of code, please tell me and i'll post them

Comment: Where you executing this code - \Log::error(json_encode(request()));

Comment: @Dmitry inside the `public function report(Exception $exception)` in the Exception/Handler.php` file

Comment: Try type-hinting the _request_ into the method's definition. `public function report(Exception $exception, Request $request) { ...`

Comment: neither... also tried in the render function where the $request is given as default by laravel, but also that return an empty request.. the only way i found is to log $_SERVER, but that's everything except beauty ahah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just `json_encode()` the entire request as many properties are private/protected and require the use of getters for access.  You will need to determine which values are important to you and build an appropriate response.

```php
$response = [
    'method' => request()->method(),
    'url' => request()->url(),
    'full_url' => request()->fullUrl(),
    'data' => request()->all(),
];
```

Then you can pass your response array as a second parameter to the log handler, without needing to use `json_encode()`.

```php
\Log::error('Request details: ', $response);
```

Comment: and why if i pass to log::error the request it prints a empty request?